# Include path in subdirectory

Tags: c++, qt, include, project

I have a Qt C++ project where the files are separated into directories.

```
/
|
|-- dir1/
|   |
|   |-- toInclude1.h
|   |
|   |-- toInclude2.h
|
|-- dir2/
|   |
|   |-- toInclude1.h
|   |
|   |-- toInclude2.h
|
|-- main.cpp
```

I understand that when I want to include in file `main.cpp` for example the `toInclude1.h` I just have to write

```
#include "dir1/toInclude1.h"
```

But if I want to include this same file in `toInclude2.h` I can write either

```
#include "dir1/toInclude1.h"
```

or

```
#include "toInclude1.h"
```

To me this seems to be a good source of ambiguity, when there are more header files with the same name but on a different path.

So my question is that which one should be used from the latter two in my case?

Comment: _'To me this seems to be a good source of ambiguity'_ You should use the way of least ambiguity, which is to provide a `-I<incl_path>` to point at a top level directory and fully specify pathes relative to this one in your `#include` directives.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You really shouldn't be `#include`ing in a header file.  If you do, then put the all thoose header files in a *seperate* sub-sub-director and have a header file include all of them.  Use that top level header file in your code.